# How to set each tab to a specific directory in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I switched from sublime to vscode.
In some cases I want to open multiple projects/folders, and the feature called 'Multi-root Workspaces' works to some extent. But I want to have one large project tab for each individual project,and each project can have many small file tabs. A picture is worth a thousand words, so this is the result i want to see:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please take the gif below for a reference, which was made [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/396#issuecomment-341387730) by [bpasero](https://github.com/bpasero).

[image]

VS Code originally did not support tabs for each dir/project. We used to have multiple windows for different dir/projects.

Multi-dir feature was well discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/396). This feature was added and explained in the doc [Multi-root Workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces).

But it is not exactly the same with some other editors.